# Remove parentheses around number in apacite

Tags: apacite

I need to remove parentheses around number (No) in bibliography. I am using `apacite`.

My setup:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
...
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

Current version:

```
Xu, Z., and Xia, M. (2012). Hesitant fuzzy entropy and cross-entropy and their 
use in multiattribute decision-making. International Journal of Intelligent 
Systems, Vol. 27(No. 9), pp. 799–822.
```

Desired version:

```
Xu, Z., and Xia, M. (2012). Hesitant fuzzy entropy and cross-entropy and their 
use in multiattribute decision-making. International Journal of Intelligent 
Systems, Vol. 27, No. 9, pp. 799–822.
```

Is there any way to format my reference like this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get “Vol.” and “No.”, unless I hardwire them in the `volume` and `number` fields, which is wrong.

Here's a change to the relevant macro that adds “Vol.” and ”No.”, also removing the parentheses.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{xu-xia-2012,
  author={Xu, Z. and Xia, M.},
  year={2012},
  title={Hesitant fuzzy entropy and cross-entropy and 
    their use in multiattribute decision-making},
  journal={International Journal of Intelligent Systems},
  volume=27,
  number=9,
  pages={799–822},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \Bem{#1}%
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, \Bem{Vol.~#2}% <--- added Vol.
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    %\unskip({#3})% <--- original
    \unskip, {No.~#3}% <--- changed
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {#4}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{xu-xia-2012}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change "&” into “and” (which would be a good thing), also add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}}
```

just after `\makeatletter`.

[image]

Comment: Works perfect. There is any solution to add pp. by changing the relevant macro ?

Comment: @remacizineb In the code, change `#4` into `pp.~#4`